# Initialize Kendo Grid grouped

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is there any way to initialize a Kendo Ui Grid (jQuery version) already grouped by a specific column?
Can't see any options on initialization or any methods group to call on databound.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It's absolutely possible to initialize a Kendo Grid grouped by a column.  This can be accomplished by using a combination of the [groupable](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/groupable) configuration of the Kendo Grid and the [group](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/group) configuration in the DataSource.

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "productName" },
    { field: "category" }
  ],
  dataSource: {
    data: [
      { productName: "Tea", category: "Beverages" },
     { productName: "Coffee", category: "Beverages" },
     { productName: "Ham", category: "Food" },
     { productName: "Bread", category: "Food" }
   ],
    group: [
      { field: "productName" }
    ]
  },
  groupable: true
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="grid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```